# Why does Florida drywall have a pebbled surface?

Tags: drywall

Why does drywall in Florida typically have a pebbled surface? Up north it is mainly smooth.

Comment: Because Florida is the most popular place for old drywall to move to when it retires.

Comment: Gives the geckos better grip on the wall?

Comment: In Minnesota, orange peel or knockdown texture is almost universal. I don't think the premise in the question is valid. It's also subjective. Voting to close.

Comment: While not a great question for this site since this is really just a taste/style thing, I must admit I have had the same question. I Ohio interior drywall is universally smooth. I wonder if it is what people expect since it looks more like old plaster (which is smooth) and people expect that as “normal”.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean an orange peel finished texture. That is a popular style that fades in and out like any fashion. Stucco exteriors are popular in the South; wood siding is popular in the North.